# Convert JArray of String from JObject to String Array in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON and part of it contains a string values like

```
 "parent_crumbs": [
    "Platforms",
    "STATS , EXPE , ESTAP",
    "Portal"
],
```

I use the below code to read  the value from the JSON object

```
 JObject _task; //parse the JSON to JOBJECT first               
 string values=    (string)_task["parent_crumbs"].ToString();
```

This will return a string with square brackets and all quotes only.

How can i convert this to a string array in C#

I can remove [ and ]  and then split on , But when , is present in string items middle the entire assumptions will break. So is any methods availabe to read from JArray to String Array

Comment: Which version of json.net/Newtonsoft.Json do you use?

Comment: Latest version from NUGET

Comment: Try  `IEnumerable<string > strings= _task[“parent_crumbs”].Select(s=>s.Value<string>();`

Comment: Could you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 5):

You didn't post the full json string, so let's assume it's something like this:

```
{
    "id": 123,
     "parent_crumbs": [
        "Platforms",
        "STATS , EXPE , ESTAP",
        "Portal"
    ]
}
```

You can create a C# model that matches this structure as follows:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("parent_crumbs")]
    public List<string> ParentCrumbs { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize the json string into an instance of a Data class:

```
string json = @"{
    ""id"": 123,
     ""parent_crumbs"": [
        ""Platforms"",
        ""STATS , EXPE , ESTAP"",
        ""Portal""
    ]
}";

Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

foreach (string crumb in data.ParentCrumbs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(crumb);
}
```

## EDIT

Instead of deserializing the whole json string you can do the following:

```
string json = @"{
    ""id"": 123,
     ""parent_crumbs"": [
        ""Platforms"",
        ""STATS , EXPE , ESTAP"",
        ""Portal""
    ]
}";

JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken crumbsToken = data.GetValue("parent_crumbs");
List<string> crumbs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(crumbsToken.ToString());

// alternative way to get the string values, as suggested by @BrianRogers
List<string> crumbs = crumbsToken.ToObject<List<string>>();
```

Comment: Its a very length y JSON and  building model for all properties is not practical for me . Around 60+ properties i have to make. Thats why i am doing inline conversion to string or JArray

Comment: @JibinMathew I added more details to my answer, please take a look.

Comment: On deserialization, note that you can create a model with fewer properties and it will work anyway.

Comment: @SandRock that's cool, I never tried it TBH - thanks for the info :-)

Comment: @RuiJarimba Don't convert the JToken to string just to turn around and deserialize it.  Instead, use [`.ToObject<T>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm) like this:  `List<string> crumbs = crumbsToken.ToObject<List<string>>();`

Comment: @BrianRogers I have edited my answer, thanks for the feedback :-)